# Folder access permission denied python [Permission: Errno 13]

Tags: python, tkinter, permission-denied

Hello everyone viewing this question and trying to solve it!
I am making a GUI-based project planner where I need to add oroject name, requirements and steps to achieve which are then saved. I am also adding a feature to add files to it according to relevancy. But when I try to test it I get this: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '<project name>'`. I don't know where I am going wrong despite of **reading many such question**. I have tried `chmod` but even that is not working. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os


WIN = Tk()
files =[]

def copy(src,dest):
    os.chmod(dest, 0o777)
    with open(src,'r') as f, open(dest,'w+') as f2:
        f2.write(f)

def start(name):
    os.startfile(name)

#<---Button functions--->
def Addfile():
    global files
    WIN.filename =  askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:",title = "choose your file")
    print(WIN.filename)
    added_fr = Frame(text_box_files)
    added_fr.pack()
    f_name = Label(added_fr,text=WIN.filename)
    f_name.pack()
    #dest = shutil.copyfile(WIN.filename, destination) 
    files.append(WIN.filename)
    f_b = Button(added_fr,text="Open",command=lambda x = WIN.filename: start(x))
    f_b.pack()

def submit():
    global files
    name = name_ent.get()
    req = text_box.get("1.0",END)
    steps = text_box_step.get("1.0",END)
    if name != "" and name not in os.listdir() and req != "" and steps != "":
        os.mkdir(name)
        with open(f"{name}\\req.txt","w") as f:
            f.write(req)
        with open(f"{name}\\steps.txt","w") as f2:
            f2.write(steps)
        os.mkdir(f"{name}\\main")
        with open(f"{name}\\main\\main.py","w") as f3:
            f3.write(f"#Main .py file of {name} project")
    elif name in os.listdir():
        messagebox.showerror("Project already exists", "A project with this name already exists! Try something else") 
    elif name=="" or req=="" or steps=="":
        messagebox.showerror("Naming error", "Project name/steps/requirement can't be left blank")

    print(files) 
    for fi in files:
        copy(fi, name) 

        

    
#<----Frames---->
head = Frame(WIN, padx=15,pady=10)
head.pack()

main_frame1 = Frame(WIN)
main_frame1.pack()

main_frame2 = Frame(WIN,highlightbackground="black" , highlightthickness=1)
main_frame2.pack()

name_frame = Frame(main_frame1,highlightbackground="black" , highlightthickness=1,padx=382,pady=3)
name_frame.pack()

requirements_frame = Frame(main_frame2)
requirements_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

files_frame = Frame(main_frame2,highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
files_frame.grid(row=0,column=1)

#<----Title---->
title = Label(head, text="Project Planner", font=("Arial bold",18))
title.pack()

#<----Name-Frame---->
name_lb = Label(name_frame,text="Project name: ").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="e")
name_ent = Entry(name_frame,width=20)
name_ent.grid(row=0,column=1)

#<----Requirements---->
requirements_lb = Label(requirements_frame, text="Requirements: ")
requirements_lb.pack()

text_box = Text(requirements_frame,width=100,height=5)
text_box.pack(side = TOP, expand = True, fill = BOTH)

#<----Step---->
step_lb = Label(requirements_frame,text="Steps/Ideas to solve: ")
step_lb.pack()

text_box_step = Text(requirements_frame,width=100,height=17)
text_box_step.pack(side = TOP, expand = True, fill = BOTH)

#<----Files---->
files_lb = Label(files_frame,text="Add files: ")
files_lb.pack()


text_box_files = Text(files_frame,width=20)
text_box_files.pack()


add = Button(files_frame,text="Add",command=Addfile)
add.pack(ipadx=30)


#<----Submit---->
submit = Button(WIN,text="Submit",command=submit)
submit.pack(ipadx=30,pady=2)

WIN.mainloop()
```

Also my operating system is **Windows**,
Please help.

Comment: Please clarify what you did to get that error.

Comment: I added a file and pressed submit button

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod): *"Although Windows supports chmod(), you can only set the file’s read-only flag with it (via the stat.S_IWRITE and stat.S_IREAD constants or a corresponding integer value). All other bits are ignored."*

Comment: Give what @KlausD. mentioned, the easiest way is to ensure that the folder that you're trying to write to has writing permissions set for the user.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Maybe I need to use it somewhere else. Please help

Comment: Oh. I found where I went wrong. When I used shutil.copy(), it got fixed.